# Easiest way to display a string from code behind asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

### I had a look at these:

[How to dislay Validation Message from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354928/how-to-dislay-validation-message-from-code-behind)

[How do I display string from code behind in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281666/how-do-i-display-string-from-code-behind-in-page)

Does anyone know a easier way?  e.g.

```
string msg = "hello";//code behind

<p><% msg %></p>
```

Comment: Define _easy_, imho the easiest and best approach is to use codebehind.

Comment: like my example, i want to display one string? Do i have it all wrong

Comment: i meant to say that it would be better to add a `Label` or `Literal` control and assign the text from codebehind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<p><%= msg %></p>
```

Add the '='. Was that what you were asking?

Comment: I tried that    does not contain a definition for 'msg' and no extension method 'msg' accepting a first argument

Comment: It's important to realise that the markup page `Inherits` the code behind, in other words it's a sub class and so using the appropriate access modifier on members is required if you want to expose the property to the sub class.

Answer (score 1):

Yours almost worked. The correct is:

```
string msg = "hello";//code behind

<p><%= msg %></p>
```

Another way is only with code behind:

```
Response.Write("<p>hello</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

.cs page

```
string msg = "hello";//code behind
```

.aspx page

```
<p><%= this.msg %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below method always works for me:

CodeBehind:

```
private string msg;
public string Msg { get { return msg; } }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   msg = "hello";
}
```

ASPX Page:

```
<p><%= Msg %></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
Response.Write(msg);
```

I hope this is what you were looking for...

Comment: That writes text to the top of the file, i doubt that this is what OP wants.

Comment: You should almost never use `Response.Write` on an asp.net `Page` because it writes the text out before the page actually renders in the browser, so  even  before the DOCTYPE tag. Without a valid DTD, the browser will render in quirks mode which is generally undesireable.